# How much efforts does it takes to let three monitors to replace VR headset program?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have a  unity project. It is developed for VR headset training usage. However, users have a strong dizzy feeling after playing the game. Now, I want to use 3 monitors to replace the VR headset so the users can look at the 3 monitors to drive. Is it a big effort to change the software code to achieve this? What can I do for the software so that it can be run in monitor?

Comment: In principle, it's pretty simple: Remove the head tracking and lock the view to vehicle-forward, have the OS register your screens as a single logical display, enjoy!  Any complications come from the nature of your project, to which you've not offered any insight.

Comment: @Immersive Thank you. How about the left hand size and the right hand side of the view? I want to have 3 monitors(left hand side, vehicle-forward and right hand side). Is it a big effort at programming ?

Comment: Only trivial effort. ;)

Comment: What would two monitors give you that one doesn? you will not see stereoscopy anyways

Comment: @zambari a lot of fullcockpit Car driving simulators use 3 monitors to simulate the front, left and right windows ;)

Comment: @derHugo makes sense, I thought he was going for left right eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is quite simple:

See [Unity Manual Multi-Display](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html)

- In your Scene have 3 `Camera` objects and set their according [Camera.targetDisplay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetDisplay.html) via the Inspector (`1`-indexed).
- To make them follow the vehicle correctly simply make them childs of the vehicle object then they are always rotated and moved along with it. Now position and rotate them according to your needs relative to the vehicle.
- In [`PlayerSettings` → `XRSettings` (at the bottom)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html) disable the `Virtual Reality Supported` since you do not want any VR-HMD move the `Camera` but it's only controlled by the vehicle transform.
- Then you also have to [activate according Displays](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Display.Activate.html) (`0`-indexes where `0` is the default monitor which is always enabled) in your case e.g.

  ```
  private void Start()
  {
      Display.displays[1].Activate();
      Display.displays[2].Activate();
  }
  ```

  *I don't know how exactly the "second" or "third" connected Monitor is defined but I guess it should match with the monitor numbering in the [system display settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027860/windows-10-view-display-settings).*